# How do I find out if a numpy array contains integers?

Tags: python, numpy

I know there is a simple solution to this but can't seem to find it at the moment.

Given a numpy array, I need to know if the array contains integers.

Checking the dtype per-se is not enough, as there are multiple int dtypes (int8, int16, int32, int64 ...).

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Found it in the [numpy book](http://templatelab.com/numpybook/)! Page 23:

> The other types in the hierarchy deﬁne particular categories of types. 
>   These categories can be useful for testing whether or not the object 
>   returned by self.dtype.type is of a particular class (using issubclass).

```
issubclass(n.dtype('int8').type, n.integer)
>>> True
issubclass(n.dtype('int16').type, n.integer)
>>> True
```

Comment: `issubclass(np.float64, np.floating)` for floating point types

Comment: Nice, works.  Alternate syntax (when dealing with an array): `issubclass(label_array.dtype.type, np.integer)`

Comment: specifically, for an np.ndarray `arr`, you'll need to inspect `arr.dtype.type`.

e.g. `is_integer = lambda arr: issubclass(arr.dtype.type, np.integer)`

Answer (score 30):

Checking for an integer type does not work for floats that are integers, e.g. `4.` Better solution is `np.equal(np.mod(x, 1), 0)`, as in:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> def isinteger(x):
...     return np.equal(np.mod(x, 1), 0)
... 
>>> foo = np.array([0., 1.5, 1.])
>>> bar = np.array([-5,  1,  2,  3, -4, -2,  0,  1,  0,  0, -1,  1])
>>> isinteger(foo)
array([ True, False,  True], dtype=bool)
>>> isinteger(bar)
array([ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
    True,  True,  True], dtype=bool)
>>> isinteger(1.5)
False
>>> isinteger(1.)
True
>>> isinteger(1)
True
```

Comment: Love this solution. Useful when one has no idea what is stored.

Answer (score 11):

This also works:

```
  n.dtype('int8').kind == 'i'
```

Comment: For unsigned dtype, kind = 'u'. A more general test should be: **some_dtype.kind in ('u','i')**

Comment: @Juh_, or just `some_dtype.kind in 'ui'`

Answer (score 10):

Numpy's issubdtype() function can be used as follows:

```
import numpy as np

size=(3,3)
A = np.random.randint(0, 255, size)
B = np.random.random(size)

print 'Array A:\n',  A
print 'Integers:', np.issubdtype(A[0,0], int)
print 'Floats:', np.issubdtype(A[0,0], float)

print '\nArray B:\n',  B
print 'Integers:', np.issubdtype(B[0,0], int)
print 'Floats:', np.issubdtype(B[0,0], float)
```

**Results:**

```
Array A:
[[  9 224  33]
 [210 117  83]
 [206 139  60]]
Integers: True
Floats: False

Array B:
[[ 0.54221849  0.96021118  0.72322367]
 [ 0.02207826  0.55162813  0.52167972]
 [ 0.74106348  0.72457807  0.9705301 ]]
Integers: False
Floats: True
```

PS. Keep in mind that the elements of an array are always of the same datatype.

Answer (score 4):

While [the accepted answer from 2009](https://stackoverflow.com/a/934652/2898712) is still valid, there is [a new and enhanced solution](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.9.0/release.html#compatibility-to-python-numbers-module) as of Numpy v0.19, released in September 2014:

> All numerical numpy types are now registered with the type hierarchy
> in the python numbers module.

This allows for checking the `dtype` against Python's [Numeric abstract base classes](https://docs.python.org/library/numbers.html).

```
issubclass(np.dtype('int32').type, numbers.Integral)
```

You can test against `numbers.Complex`, `numbers.Real` and `numbers.Integral`.

Comment: `isinstance(np.dtype('int8'), numbers.Integral)` still gives you `False`, so I don't see a way to not use `.type`

Comment: I removed the `.type` suggestion. Thanks for the hint @TimofeiBondarev

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to determine if a dtype is integral, then you look at the type hierarchy as the other answers suggest. However, if you want to check floats that may contain integers, you can use `(x % 1) == 0`, or the ufunc I recently wrote just for the purpose: https://github.com/madphysicist/is_integer_ufunc. After installing, you could run it with

```
from is_integer_ufunc import is_integer

is_integer(x)
```

It operates on integers and floating point types equally. The return value is a mask. For integer types, it is always True, while for floats it indicates the elements containing integer values.