# setting "if" to make sure variable is a number and not a letter/symbol

Tags: python, if-statement

How do I create an "if" statement to make sure the input variable is a number and not a letter?

```
radius = input ('What is the radius of the circle? ') 

#need if statement here following the input above in case user
#presses a wrong key
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3501382/checking-whether-a-variable-is-an-integer-or-not

Comment: As a side note, `**radius = ...` is no python syntax that I know of.  I assume that just put the `**` in there when you posted the question, but for future reference, I'd leave those off and let the StackOverflow markup do it's job :).  It's nice if we can copy/paste your code and start to play around without having to guess at what your *actual* code looks like.

Comment: the ** before 'radius' happened when i pressed the bold button to highlight the text; that's why you see them again at the end of my post; apologies for the mistake

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
if isinstance(radius, (int, float)):
    #do stuff
else:
    raise TypeError  #or whatever you wanna do
```

Comment: This should be if isinstance(radius, int) or isinstance(radius, float).  Alternatively, someone can use if type(radius) in [int, float] which is a bit more elegant.

Comment: @vkontori -- I don't like `type(radius) in (int,float)`, but `isinstance` can check for more than one type.  `isinstance(radius,(float,int))` -- you could probably even do a little better with `isinstance(radius,numbers.Number)`

Comment: @mgilson -- for the argument type vs isinstance see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549801/differences-between-isinstance-and-type-in-python, still the order of the arguments needs to be fixed...

Comment: @vkontori -- That post seems to support my comment, but yes, you're definitely correct that the order needed to be fixed.  That post is a good find.  Posts by Alex are generally well written and informative -- I suppose that's why he's the top python answerer of all time.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you're using python2.x: I think a better way to do this is to get the input as `raw_input`.  Then you *know* it's a string:

```
r = raw_input("enter radius:")  #raw_input always returns a string
```

The python3.x equivalent of the above statement is:

```
r = input("enter radius:")      #input on python3.x always returns a string
```

Now, construct a float from that (or try to):

```
try:
    radius = float(r)
except ValueError:
    print "bad input"
```

*Some further notes on python version compatibility*

In python2.x, `input(...)` is equivalent to `eval(raw_input(...))` which means that you never know what you're going to get returned from it -- You could even get a `SyntaxError` raised inside `input`!

**Warning about using** `input` **on python2.x**

As a side note, My proposed procedure makes your program safe from all sorts of attacks.  Consider how bad a day it would be if a user put in:

```
__import__('os').remove('some/important/file')
```

instead of a number when prompted!  If you're `eval`ing that previous statement by using `input` on python2.x, or by using `eval` explicitly, you've just had `some/important/file` deleted.  Oops.

Comment: that's a good point; anyway, this prog is not being distributed or used by anyone besides me; it's for me to practice learning, but i'll keep your advice for the future