# Python: Why checking of types is a big no

Tags: python

I am learning python and was writing this game, where the program picks a random number and asks the user to guess the number. In this case, a user can enter an empty string or an alphabet by mistake. So, i felt the need to check the type of the user input before doing the comparison as shown below. Also, this lead me to the following stackoverflow entry
[Checking whether a variable is an integer or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3501382/checking-whether-a-variable-is-an-integer-or-not)

My question is why checking of types is considered a bad practice and how can i accomplish my task by not checking the type?

```
import random

num =  random.randint(1,10)

while True:
    guess = input('Guess a number between 1 and 10: ')
    if(bool(guess)):
            try:
                    guess = int(guess)
            except:
                    print("Please enter a numeric value")
                    continue
    else:
            print("you have to enter some number")
            continue
    if guess == num:
            print("you guessed it right")
            break
    elif guess < num:
            print("Try higher")
    elif guess > num:
            print("Try lower")
```

Comment: You aren't checking for any types in your above code, it's fine.

Comment: You're not checking the type here, you're converting from a string to an integer which is ok.

Checking the type would mean using `isinstance(guess, int)`, for example. And this is bad practice because it leaves you without the benefits of OOP.

Comment: first ask for forgiveness than for permission- as the linked post told you! Why should you check if it is an integer, if you must (should) integrate exceptionhandling...

Answer (score 1):

As the comments have stated, at no point do you check the type. What you do is **validate and convert the input**, which is appropriate for this program (and indeed, should be used in *any* program that accepts user input).

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
import random

num = random.randint(1, 10)
while True:
    try:
        guess = int(input('Guess a number between 1 and 10: '))
        if guess == num:
            print('You have guessed the correct number')
            break
        if guess < num:
            print('Try higher.')
        else:
            print('Try lower.')
    except ValueError:
        print('Please enter a number.')
```

The idea is that simply converting the input and handling the error leads to much cleaner code.  In Python circles, checking the type via `isinstance` is known as [*Look Before You Leap*](http://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-lbyl) which is discouraged.  Just attempt the operation in question and handle the failure case (usually by exception handling).  This is termed [*Easier to Ask Forgiveness than Permission*](http://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-eafp).