# How do I take a value produced by a return from a function in python and make it a variable?

Tags: python, numbers

So i'm creating a little experimental python program and I'm using a little tidbit of code (shown below) to determine if a number is whole or has decimal places.

```
def isWhole(x):
if(x%1 == 0):
    return "1"
else:
    return "2"
```

My problem is that no matter where I go I can't find a way to just take the returned value and assign it to a variable...

Sorry if I seem like an absolute spurglord noob for asking this question but I never even knew that functions could "return" until about 2 days ago, so yeah...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3501382/checking-whether-a-variable-is-an-integer-or-not

You should return true or False instead of 1 or 2 :)

Comment: After you figure out what value to use for `%` (hint: x % 1 is ALWAYS 0), you can use `(1,2)[x % 2]` for example to return 1 or 2 based on even / odd

Comment: @Florian: In this case you could do that with `return x%1 == 0` (which would always return `True`, for the previously stated reason).

Answer (score 2):

like this:

```
def isWhole(x):
    if(x%1 == 0):
        return "1"
    else:
        return "2"

my_var = isWhole(4)
```

Answer (score 1):

The return value will always be 1.

```
def isWhole(x):
    if x % 1 == 0:
        return "1"
    else:
        return "2"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    k = isWhole(4)
    print(k)
```

Answer (score 1):

Answering your question, how to assign a variable, just assign it to the output of the function as below:

```
var = isWhole(4) #Put any number in instead of 4
```

As long as you have a `return` in your function, you can assign a variable to the output:

```
>>> def foo():
...    return "bar"
...
>>> var = foo()
>>> var
"bar"
>>>
```

However if you do not have a `return`, then it returns `None`, so beware :)

```
>>> def bar():
...    print "foo"
...
>>> var = bar()
foo
>>> var
None
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have explained, you can just assign the result of calling the function to a variable name to save the value. Perhaps equally important though, is the fact that the code shown in your function will always return `"1"` since the value of `x%1` is always going to be `0` regardless of the value of `x` (assuming its value is non-zero and a type with a [modulo operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation)).

I would suggest that tou instead implement your function to return a `True` or `False` value and do it like the following:

```
def is_whole(x):
    return float(x).is_integer()
```

(See the [`is_integer`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=is_integer#float.is_integer) documentation for more information.)

You can assign the result of calling this function to a variable as shown below:

```
result1 = is_whole(21./7.)  # assign function return value to a variable
result2 = is_whole(22./7.)  # assign function return value to another variable

print(result1)  # --> True
print(result2)  # --> False
```