# Making a variable integer input only == an integer in Python

Tags: python, if-statement

Im trying to make my variable integer input to be only == to an integer, and if its not I want to print and error message. I have put this in a *if* statement. I always get an error when I input a string instead of my error message.

```
age = int(input("Enter age:"))

if age != int:
print("Not a number")
```

Comment: here is a discussion about how to test if a string represents an integer in python or not: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3501382/checking-whether-a-variable-is-an-integer-or-not

Comment: this is for python 3, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to use `raw_input` instead of input

if you want this to repeat until you have the correct value you can do this

```
while True:
    try:
        age = int(raw_input("Enter age:"))
    except ValueError:
        print("Not a number")

    if age == desired_age: # note I changed the name of your variable to desired_age instead of int
        break
```

I dont recommend you use variable names like int... its generally a bad practice

Comment: still getting a traceback error. thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: @PatrickCallahan did you see my latest edit? there isn't a way you could be

Comment: that looks like something the OP might want. let's see... +1

Comment: yea that answered my question on how to handle an input if its not an integer. im new to programming so forgive me lol

Comment: @PatrickCallahan no worries. feel free to ask me questions and I can answer it for you :)

Comment: awesome, yea this is my intro to programming class, so im trying to work out the kinks here.

Comment: @PatrickCallahan cool! yea StackOverflow is the place to go for programming questions. some basic things to know... when you cast anything to a type you need to wrap it in a try except because it will raise an exception if the input is invalid. the while loop I put in there will continue to prompt user input until the correct value is inputted.. if you want to get a specific age :) dont forget to mark an answer as accepted (doesn't have to be mine) so this question can be closed! :)

Answer (score 2):

from the discussion i posted the link above:

```
age = input("Enter age:")  # raw_input("Enter age:") in python 2

try:
    age = int(age)
except ValueError:
    print('not a number!')
```

the idea is to try to cast `age` to an integer.

your attempt of `age != int` will always fail; `age` is a string (or an int if you were successful in casting it) and `int` is a class.

Comment: not sure that is the problem the OP had. he was already casting it to an int in the previous line. It looks like `int` is a variable name

Comment: yea.... Its hard to tell since people use types as variable names O.o strange imo. but nice answer all around +1 :)

Comment: So i have to convert the variable using the int()? And that did work, thanks

Comment: yes, you try to cast it to an `int` an hope that works. checking for a string that is a valid int yourself is surprisingly difficult...