# Try-Except Clause Ignored in Linear List Insertion Algorithm Using Bisect Module (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, debugging, bisect

I'm trying to insert an element into a linear list using `input()` with `bisect()` and `insort()` functions of the `bisect` module in Python 3.7. To accept only integer inputs, I tried adding a try-except clause (as suggested in an answer to: [Making a variable integer input only == an integer in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32998546/making-a-variable-integer-input-only-an-integer-in-python#)) as:

```
import bisect
m=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
print("The list is:", m)
item=input("Enter element to be inserted:")
try:
    item=int(item)
except ValueError:
    print("Invalid!")
ind=bisect.bisect(m, item)
bisect.insort(m, item)
print("Item inserted at index:", ind)
print("List after insertion:", m)
```

I expected Python to catch the exception on entering a float, but it ignored the try-except clause and displayed this rather:

> ind=bisect.bisect(m, item)
>   TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

What could be the possible issue?

Edit:

On changing `except ValueError` to `except TypeError` and entering '5.0', I received ValueError:

> item=int(item)
>   ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '5.0'

Comment: after the exception the program continues. Not logical.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I'm new to programming; forgive me :) A method using ```split()``` to detect non-int worked better.

Comment: @Kartik a `split()`-based method may not be very robust, e.g. `s = 'fgsdgfd'` may fool a `len(s.split('.')) == 1` check.

Comment: @norok2 Oh, it did. Thanks, tho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that while you catch the error with the `try`/`except` clause, you do not do anything to make sure that `item` is actually a `int`.

A more reasonable approach is to loop until the input can be converted to `int`, for example:

```
import bisect


m = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
print("The list is:", m)

# : loop until the input is actually valid
is_valid = False
while not is_valid:
    item = input("Enter element to be inserted:")
    try:
        item = int(item)
    except ValueError:
        print("Invalid!")
    else:
        is_valid = True

ind = bisect.bisect(m, item)
bisect.insort(m, item)
print("Item inserted at index:", ind)
print("List after insertion:", m)
```

---

Note that `input()` always gets a `str` and `int('5.0')` also throws a `ValueError`, if you want to handle that case as well, use two `try`s, e.g.:

```
import bisect


m = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
print("The list is:", m)

is_valid = False
while not is_valid:
    item = input("Enter element to be inserted:")
    try:
        item = int(item)
    except ValueError:
        try:
            item = int(round(float(item)))
            # or just: item = float(item) -- depends on what you want
        except ValueError:
            print("Invalid!")
        else:
            is_valid = True
    else:
        is_valid = True

ind = bisect.bisect(m, item)
bisect.insort(m, item)
print("Item inserted at index:", ind)
print("List after insertion:", m)
```