# getting only positive number from a list that containing heterogeneous data type item in python 3

Tags: python, list

## I have a list of items with heterogeneous data types contained in strings.

```
lst=['1','err','-1',' ','155']
```

From that, I would like to obtain a new list with only the positive numbers:  `new_lst=[1,155]`

I have tried to avoid negative numbers as shown below. However, I am not able to avoid the strings and empty strings:

```
lst1=int(lst)
for i in lst1:
    if i<0:
    print i
    else:
    continue

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Dev/Documents/Assignment-2/test-2.py", line 22, in <module>
    c3=int(row[3])
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'err'
>>>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Checking whether a variable is an integer or not](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3501382/checking-whether-a-variable-is-an-integer-or-not)

Comment: This sounds like homework so instead of giving you working code, I will give you an idea of how to solve it. First, iterate your list and for each item in the list, `try` to convert it to an `int`. If the conversion is successful, check to see if the number is greater than 0. If so, then you can add it to your list of positive numbers.

Comment: Wrap your "int()" call in a try / except.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`lst1=int(lst)` is the code that is raising the exception. This is essentially trying to cast a `list` into an `int` (which you cannot do).

What you want to do is iterate through `lst`, and for each element, determine if the element can be cast into an `int`, then check if the element (as an `int`) is positive.

---

You could do something like this:

```
lst = ['1','err','-1',' ','155']
new_lst = []

for i in lst:
    try:
        int_i = int(i)           # try to cast i to an int
        if int_i > 0:
            new_lst.append(int_i)
    except ValueError:           # ValueError is raised, i cannot be cast into an int
        pass                     # continue to the next element
```

---

**EDIT**: Added `ValueError` for completeness, see @BigZ's answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
lst=['1','err','-1',' ','155']
newlst = []
for i in lst:
    try:
        if int(i) >= 0:
            newlst.append(int(i))
    except ValueError:
        pass
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a one liner that tests if an element is actually a number.  If this check isn't done, `int(x)` will not work and throw and exception.

```
lst=['1','err','-1',' ','155']
lst1 = filter(None,[(lambda x: x if x.isdigit() and int(x) > 0 else None) (x) for x in lst])
```

Answer (score 2):

If you just have ints and considering you only want to keep positive numbers  `str.isdigit` is sufficient as you don't care if `"-1"` fails on `str.isdigit`:

```
lst[:] = (ele for ele in lst if ele.isdigit() and int(ele) > 0)
```

If you did possibly have floats then all the answers using `int` and a try/except would also fail, if you want to cover "1.0" etc.. you would need to cast to float in the try.

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize `pd.to_numeric` with argument `coerce` to essentially remove non-numbers by changing them to Nan, and then extract only positive numbers.

```
[x for x in  pd.to_numeric(lst, errors='coerce') if x > 0]
```