# Checking whether a string is convertible to an integer

Tags: python

I wanted to check whether a string is convertible to an integer inside lambda expression.

```
import re,time
rdd = sc.textFile("file:///home/vdpqa/sample.gz")
new1 = rdd.map(lambda x: re.split('/|\.|\|',x))
    .filter(lambda arr: (len(arr) > 9) and isinstance(arr[7],int)).map(lambda x: x[:9])

new = new1.map(lambda x: [x[0],x[1],x[3],
        time.strftime('%Y%m%d', time.localtime(int(x[7])/1000000)),x[8]])
```

I checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3501382/checking-whether-a-variable-is-an-integer-or-not) but it didn't help:

```
>>> isinstance(1448379000595770,int)
True
>>> isinstance('1448379000595770',int)
False
```

Comment: I would recommend ditching the `lambda`s and just defining ordinary functions.

Comment: The surest way is to try and cast the string to an int and see if it raises an exception. And probably not in a lambda function.

Answer (score 5):

In an ordinary function the best approach would be:

```
def canBeNumber(n):
    try:
        int(n)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        # Not a number
        return False
```