# How to check if string is (int or float) in Python 2.7

Tags: python, string, floating-point, int

I know similar questions have been asked and answered before like here: [How do I check if a string is a number (float) in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/354038/how-do-i-check-if-a-string-is-a-number-float-in-python)

However, it does not provide the answer I'm looking for. What I'm trying to do is this:

```
def main():
    print "enter a number"
    choice = raw_input("> ")
    # At this point, I want to evaluate whether choice is a number.
    # I don't care if it's an int or float, I will accept either.

    # If it's a number (int or float), print "You have entered a number."
    # Else, print "That's not a number."
main()
```

Answers to most of the questions suggest using try..except, but this only allows me to evaluate int or floats exclusively, i.e

```
def is_number(s):
    try:
        float(choice)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False
```

If I use this code, int values will end up in the exception.

Other methods I've seen include str.isdigit. However, this returns True for int and false for float.

Comment: `float('123')` returns `123.0` and doesn't give you `ValueError`. So your function works fine.

Comment: *"If I use this code, int values will end up in the exception"* - nope. Please actually try these things before asking.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification guys. I did try that method before asking this but I couldn't get it to work. Must have made a mistake somewhere. Either way, it works now just like you guys mentioned. Thanks!!

Comment: Does this answer your question:
[Checking whether a variable is an integer or not](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3501382/checking-whether-a-variable-is-an-integer-or-not) Thomas

Comment: Solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64132078/8321339

Answer (score 4):

In your case it is enough to simply check whether the input can be converted to a float in a try/except block. The conversion will be successful for any string that could have been converted to an integer as well.

Answer (score 2):

the function you used should be converting int and float values in the form of a string to a float successfully. for some reason you want to specifically want to find weather it is an int or float consider this change.

```
def is_int_or_float(s):
    ''' return 1 for int, 2 for float, -1 for not a number'''
    try:
        float(s)

        return 1 if s.count('.')==0 else 2
    except ValueError:
        return -1
print is_int_or_float('12')
print is_int_or_float('12.3')
print is_int_or_float('ads')
```

here is the result

```
python test.py
1
2
-1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write your own function,

```
def is_int_or_float(a):
    if type(a) is int or type(a) is float:
        return True
    else:
       return False
```

You can write even more compact program. Between please do that yourself.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `isstance()` method and literal_eval

example

```
from ast import literal_eval

   isinstance(literal_eval('3'),int)
```

returns

```
True
```

or you can use json.

```
import json

isinstance(json.loads('3'),int)
```

return

```
True
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but I did a simple check:

```
    var = 3

    try: #if it can be converted to a float, it's true
        float(var) 
    except: # it it can't be converted to a float, it's false
        do stuff with the var
```