# How do I say, if variable = any integer, in Python 2x

Tags: python

```
import random 

print ("hello")

user_friend1 = raw_input("Name one of your friends: ")

user_friend2 = raw_input("Name another friend: ")
# inputs for user
friends = [user_friend1,user_friend2] 

best_friend = random.sample(friends, 1)
```

I want to loop it so that if a user types an integer to a question then it will ask the question again, i need it for both questions `user_friend` 1 and 2

```
print ("your best friend is %s") % (best_friend)
```

Comment: [Google](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3501382/1790644) it?

Comment: `if type(variable) == int: #do something`

Comment: `isinstance(variable, int)` would be more pythonic, no? @JoshuaNixon

Comment: @JamesR not going to lie I've never seen that. yes it would be better. Going to have to change my computing coursework now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use this**

```
import random
while True:
    friend1 = raw_input("Name one of your friends: ")
    try:
        val = int(friend1)
    except ValueError:
        break
    print("Enter valid name")
while True:
    friend2 = raw_input("Name another friend: ")
    try:
        val = int(friend2)
    except ValueError:
        break
    print("Enter valid name")
friends = [friend1,friend2]
best_friend = random.sample(friends, 1)
print("your bestfriend is %s" %(best_friend))
```

**Output**

```
Name one of your friends: 1
Enter valid name

Name one of your friends: 1
Enter valid name

Name one of your friends: tilak

Name another friend: varma
your bestfriend is ['varma']
```

Comment: I want to ask the question twice, what would I do then? type it in twice?

Comment: see the complete solution to your work as i edited it now

Comment: it's saying that my best friend is 1 (the integer I inputted)?

Comment: see the ouput that i edited , it does show the input numbers

Comment: what do you mean by 'val'?

Comment: just copy this code into your code and execute it .. val is just a variable that will be initialised if given is integer

Comment: did you get this now, upvote and accept my answer if you do.

Answer (score 1):

```
if type(variable) == int:
```

This gets the type of the variable and compares it to the class `int`

Answer (score 0):

You should use `isinstance()`

```
if isinstance(variable, int):
    do_something()
```