# How to indicate IF condition that only include INT

Tags: python

I have just started out learning python and needed some help.

Let's say I have created a simple calculator whereby all it do is just finding the average of the sum.

```
a = input("First number")
b = input("Second number")
c = input("Third number")

if():
    avg = (a+b+c)/3
print'Average:%.2f' %avg
else:
  ............
```

How am I supposed to write the if condition to indicate that IF and only if a b and c are int.

I put it as input() because I want to give it an option whereby people who may keyed in something that is not a number such as 'ABC'.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Checking whether a variable is an integer or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3501382/checking-whether-a-variable-is-an-integer-or-not)

Comment: Don't use `input` in python2. You should use `a = int(raw_input("First number"))` etc.

Comment: Well, `input()` returns string, so you can check it using `isdigit()` and if it returns True, then You can convert it to a int

Comment: @JohnLaRooy I didn't want it to convert it to INT upon keying in. I am leaving an option whereby people who key in something that is not a number so I will produce an error message out.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if string input is a number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5424716/how-to-check-if-string-input-is-a-number)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if a.isdigit() and b.isdigit() and c.isdigit():
     avg = (int(a) + int(b) + int(c))/3
```

Comment: ``isdigit()`` will not work for negative integers as it only checks for the presence of digit characters.

Comment: please explain why this helps with the problem in the Q.

Answer (score 0):

The if condition to test a, b, c are integers will be:

```
if (isinstance( a , int ) and isinstance( b , int ) and isinstance( c , int )):
```

For example , code like this:

```
a = "asdasd"
b = 2
c = 3
# if(int(a) and int(b) and int(c)):
if (isinstance( a , int ) and isinstance( b , int ) and isinstance( c , int )):
    print("integers")
else:
    print("not integers")
```

Output for the above example:

```
not integers
```

Comment: @TomKarzes , sorry , I searched for it and tested it so I felt it was correct.
thanks for feedback , should I remove this answer or improve it ?

Comment: @TomKarzes I corrected the answer , please check , thanks

Comment: That's better, although in Python 2 (which OP is apparently using), it will not recognize longs as integers.  In Python 2, you can use `isinstance(v, (int, long))`.

Comment: @TomKarzes thanks for feedback & explaining
I hope whoever downvoted the wrong answer will upvote the updated correct one.

Comment: It wasn't me, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for every variable, first check is it INT , second check is it STR representing INT:

```
if isinstance(a, int) or (str(a)[0] == '-' and str(a)[1:].isdigit()) or str(a).isdigit():
    print('integer')
else:
    print('not integer')
```

replace bc if you have integer below zero isdigit() return false. Python 2.7

Comment: That's an interesting way to check for an integer but the sign can only be the first character and appear once. Right now you will replace multiple characters wherever they are in the string causing false positives. I guess you could go with something like ``(a[0] == '-' and a[1:].isdigit()) or a.isdigit()``.

Comment: yeah, u right, i missed that there could be multiple '-' at any index,  corrected  answer

Answer (score -1):

```
import types

if type(a) == types.IntType and type(b) == types.IntType and type(c) == types.IntType:

     ....

     ....
```