# Why does this show as not an integer when I input an integer? (Python)

Tags: python, python-2.7

As you can tell, I am a fairly novice Python coder. As of current I am just making some little test programs and trying to ensure all my indentation and whatever is done properly before trying any large programs.
So I am trying to ensure that if an input is not an integer, then the program outputs a message saying an integer must be inputted. However, with the current code I have (which I think should be correct) regardless of the answer the "please input an integer" message is outputted. What have I done wrong? Here is the code:

```
a = input("What is your age?")
b = 7
c = ((a-2) * 4) +25
if a == int:
    print "Your age in a small dog's years is:", ((a-2) * 4)+28
    print "Your age in a medium sized dog's years is:", ((a-2) * 6)+27
    print "Your age in a big dog's years is:", ((a-2) * 9)+22
    print "Your age in cat years is:", c
    print "Your age in guinea pig years is:", a * 15
    print "Your age in hamster years is:", a * 20
    print "Your age in pig years is:", ((a-1) * 4)+18
    print "Your age in goldfish years is:", ((a-1) * 8)+188
    print "Your age in cow years is:", ((a-1) * 4)+14
    print "Your age in horse years is:", a * 3
    print "Your age in goat years is:", ((a-1) * 6)+18
    print "Your age in rabbit years is:", ((a-1) * 8)+20
    print "Your age in chinchilla years is:", ((a-1) * 7)+17
elif a != int:
    print "You must enter an integer!"
```

It works otherwise, it's just this little end two lines that seem to ruin it.
Thanks.

Comment: `a == int` is not the way you check the type of a variable.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3501382/checking-whether-a-variable-is-an-integer-or-not

Comment: make sure your input are integers `int(input())`. With your current implementation check `type(a) and you will see it says string`

Comment: English "is": are you a human? Python `==`: are you the same thing as the concept of humanity (i.e. is every human a kind of you); or failing that, do you have the same numerical value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python 3:

```
a = input("What is your age?") # this is a string input
a = int(input("What is your age?")) # you need an integer input
elif(isinstance(a, int)) # this is how you check if a is integer
```

For your case in Python 2:

```
a = raw_input("What is your age?") # input is interpreted as unicode here

try:
  a = int(a)
  b = 7
  c = ((a-2) * 4) +25
  print "Your age in a small dog's years is:", ((a-2) * 4)+28
except:
  print "You must enter an integer!"
```

Comment: `a = input("What is your age?")
b = 7
c = ((a-2) * 4) +25
if(isinstance(a, int)):
#Stuff
else:
    print "You must input an integer!"
`

Comment: If i enter something other than a number it gives me errors?

Comment: ah I see, you're using python2. Let me update the answer

Comment: also, I would suggest not using `input()` in python 2