# How to test a string as a list of integers Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

So im trying to accept input of an RGB color values,which means they have to be integers within 0-255,such as:

> 123,245,230

but i want to make sure that they have formatted it correctly, so i'm taking the input as a string and im trying to force it into a list.
my original solution was

> ```
>     colorList=colorListString.split(",")
>     for i in range(3):
>         colorList[i]=int(colorList[i])
>     colorMatrix+=[colorList]
> ```

but this doesn't make sure that there is always 3 values, so i complicated it to first make sure that the input was 3 values determined with

> ```
>    while colorListString.count(",") !=2: 
>         print("Color number ",x+1,": ")
>         colorListString=input()
> ```

but now im running into the problem that i dont know how to make sure that the three values are indeed integers, and keep that neatly within the while loop

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Checking whether a variable is an integer or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3501382/checking-whether-a-variable-is-an-integer-or-not)

Comment: well, i know i can use String.isNumeric,
but my biggest problem is including this without my code getting huge, for what seems like a simple problem

Comment: You probably also want those values to be in a *certain* range?

Comment: Yes, within 0 to 255, just edited the original post to clarify

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to force an exception to be thrown if they enter more then 3 numbers, there are a few ways to do it:

```
>>> colorListString = '255, 255, 255, 255'
>>> # Unpacking
>>> r, g, b = colorListString.split(",")
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 3)
>>> # maxsplit argument to split
>>> colorList = colorListString.split(",", 2)
>>> for i in range(3): colorList[i]=int(colorList[i])
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ' 255, 255'
>>> # Just check it manually
>>> colorList = colorListString.split(",")
>>> if len(colorList != 3) raise ValueError('RGB please')
ValueError: RGB please
```

No need to get any fancier, like counting the commas before the split or using a regex.

Comment: well, i didnt necessarily want an exception, i just want it to repeat the input, error message would just be a bonus, but not required

Comment: @YSquaredYobozo Well then, you can change the last one to do anything you want after the `if`, and the others, you can wrap in `try`/`except` to handle the exception.

Answer (score 2):

Regex should help.

```
import re
s = "123,245,230"

if re.match("^\d{3},\d{3},\d{3}$", s):
    #process
```

Comment: the only problem with this is it requires the number be 3 digits long, so inputs like 2 have to be written as 002, unless there is a way around that?

Comment: You can then use \d{2,3}

Comment: is there a way to specify the number value being between 0 and 255 with regex in this manner?

Answer (score 0):

Im not clear on whatg you're trying to do with the while loop.

Also you could check that the value is a valid rgb value as per below:

```
colorListString = '123,245,230'
colorMatrix = []
colorList =colorListString.split(",")
if len(colorList)==3:
    for i in range(3):
        val = int(colorList[i])
        if val <= 255 and val >= 0: 
            colorList[i] = val
    colorMatrix +=[colorList]
    print(colorMatrix)
```

Comment: the While loop was just me saying that "if its not a proper input, ask again"

Answer (score 0):

Simple ***1-liner*** without `regex`:

```
s = "123,245,230"
if all(x <= 3 for x in [len(i) if int(i) >= 0 and int(i) <= 255 else 4 for i in s.split(',')]):
    # process
```

This works with strings like `2,123,220`. You don't require to use `002,123,220`.

Also takes care that the 3-digit number in the string separated by comma is between `0` and `255`.

Comment: but this doesnt specify that the input has to be between 0 and 255

Comment: Aww, missed that one. I've updated my answer. It's a quick trick but works.