# Print two-dimensional array in Python w/ if statement

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array, printing

I have looked at other posts in regard to this. However, they all seem to use list comprehension, thus not allowing for checks on each individual element of the 2d array.

I am wanting to print a 2d array, containing some strings and some ints. Since I am converting those ints into an octal representation using `{:o}`, I want to be able to check whether an element of the array is an int or string before printing it. Since printing a string with `{:o}` throws an error.

```
# Desired outcome:
[['s', 9], [0, 1]]

's' 11
 0   1
```

Help would be much appreciated as I cannot figure out how to do this.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3501382/checking-whether-a-variable-is-an-integer-or-not

Comment: you are asking 2 questions which already have an answer

Comment: `for l in values: for i in l: if instanceof(i, int): ...`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This map the right format to the value in the list according to his type (`str` or `int`).

```
values = [['s', 9], [0, 1]]

for pair in values:
    print(*map(lambda value: ('{:o}' if isinstance(value, int) else '{}').format(value), pair))
```

output:

```
s 11
0 1
```

You can add tick if you want with `"'{}'"` instead of `'{}'`.