# Python Integers and elifs

Tags: python, integer

I am making an AI, I want the code to understand that something is an integer

```
elif inp==("i am", int):
  print("You are "x" years old")
```

`inp` is my variable

```
elif="i am", int ,"years old":
  print("You are", int ,"years old")
```

This is what I want. But for it to actually work, I want it to understand that there is an integer there.

If they said  "`I am awesome`" it would do it, but if they put "`I am 14`" it would print `You are "x" years old`. I am ok with the printing bit and with how old they actually are. But, I just want the code to recognize that there is a number there.

Comment: Use regex to search if int in string

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3501382/checking-whether-a-variable-is-an-integer-or-not

Comment: why not accept, upvote an answer? [why-vote?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given simple text, it is fairly easy to extract an integer (python 3 code):

```
import re

while True:

    # I have no idea where your text is coming from, this is for testing
    line = input("enter text: ")
    if not line: break

    # The regular depression means "one or more characters in the range 0-9"
    m = re.search(r'([0-9]+)', line)
    if m:
        print(m.groups()[0])   # << This hold the integer string

    # if m is false, there is no integer
```

If there could be more than one integer then a different solution might be required.

Answer (score 0):

If your input string is always going to be in same format, i.e. last word would be integer or something else. You could try:

```
my_input_list = my_input.split()  # Split your sentence into list
last_word = my_input_list[-1]     # Get last word
if isinstance(last_word , int):   # Check is last word in "int" type
    print("You are {age}" years old) 
else: 
    print(my_input)
```

But as you are writing `AI`, your code will get more complicated in future. You should explore using `regex` as @Rakesh mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Add a type validation before printing you can also add `raise` `TypeError` or `InputError` if you want to.

```
if type(age) == type(1):
    #continue with printing
else:
    raise InputError('age must be an integer)
```

Or better still `print('age must be an integer ')` instead of raising error

Comment: it is not advisable to use `type()` for this. Python has `isinstance()` function for this very purpose. Read this for more info https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549801/what-are-the-differences-between-type-and-isinstance