# need stopping if input not number

Tags: python, python-3.6

my code not stop in line 9-10 when inserted words, I would like it to continue only when numbers are entered

```py
from cs50 import get_int

numbers = []

while True:

    number = get_int("number: ")

    if not number:   #  here  #
        break        #  here  #

    if number not in numbers:
        numbers.append(number)

print()
for number in numbers:
    print(number)
```

need stopping if input not number

Comment: There's no point tagging your question will contradictory Python version numbers.

Comment: What is `from cs50 import get_int`? What is the `get_int` function here?

Comment: We need to know what this `get_int` returns, would throw a exception in case of non int value came through or will return `None`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can parse the input string to be a number or not in a `while True` loop, if it is not a number, break the loop, else keep asking.

```
numbers = []

while True:

    #Ask for input
    s = input("number: ")
    number = 0

    #Try to parse the string as a number, if you cannot, break the loop
    try:
        number = int(s)
    except:
        break

    #If you can parse the string as a number, add it to the list
    numbers.append(number)

print(numbers)
```

Sample outputs will be

```
number: 123
number: 456
number: 789
number: abc
[123, 456, 789]
```

Comment: wow thanks, I did not know some of these functions yet, as' try' and 'except'

Comment: Sorry if this is slightly advanced for you! I can give you something simpler which you might understand! If the answer helped you. Please mark it as accepted :)

Comment: it is not necessary, although I started this week I managed to understand, thanks!

Comment: sure, no worries!

Answer (score 0):

In Python 3, you can use the following to ensure `number` is an integer (whole number):

```py
isinstance(number, int)
```

If either an integer or a float (number with decimals) is allowed, you can use the following:

```py
isinstance(number, (int, float))
```

I highly recommend reading more about this subject in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3501382/checking-whether-a-variable-is-an-integer-or-not).

Comment: i'm starting reading about python in this week, thanks for recommendation, I'll read right now hahaha

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to define a new function to do that.

```
numbers = []
while True:
    number = input("number: ")
    try:
        number = int(number)
        if number not in numbers:
            numbers.append(number)
    except:
        break   

print (numbers)
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
try:
    if number == int(number):
        if number not in numbers:
           numbers.append(number)

except:
    #invalid input will throw you into this block
    break
```