# I have a dataset containing both strings and integer, how do I write a program that will only read the integer values on Python?

Tags: python

Need it to only read the integer values, and not the strings.

This is an example of a line in the text file:

```
yye5     mooProject   No     yeetcity   Nrn de   0      .1       .5       0
```

We want to skip the first 5 columns (`Nrn de` is one column) and put every line in the file (which looks like this) into a numpy or pandas array.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3501382/checking-whether-a-variable-is-an-integer-or-not

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Try/Except block is your friend.

```
x =  ('yye5','mooProject','No','yeetcity','Nrn','de','0','.1','.5','0')
result = []
for i in x:
    try:
        result.append(float(i))
    except ValueError:
        pass

print(result)
```

Comment: Thank you sir, but this did not work as it did not append any values to result, so an error must have been produced every time.

Comment: Thank you, now I tested it and it works. But for some reason everything comes out in 1 line.  0  /n .1 /n .5 /n 0

Comment: I am not sure how that is possible.  It is printing a list.  You must be using some quirky editor.  Line breaks would mean that it is converting the list into a string result.  That does not happen in the code above.