# Change values in dataframe using 'where' in python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I tried to change the values in those columns which dtypes are numeric values. But my code doesn't work.

dataframe name: `mergedDF`

```
for c, dtype in zip(mergedDF.columns,mergedDF.dtypes):
    if dtype == np.int64:
        mergedDF[c].where(mergedDF[c]> 0,1)
```

It basically changed nothing. When I tried to assign variable names it changed everything to `1`

```
if dtype == np.int64:
    mergedDF[c] = mergedDF[c].where(mergedDF[c]> 0,1)
```

input:

```
col1   col2   col3
1       2       0
4       0       1
2       2       0
```

expected output:

```
col1   col2   col3
1       1       0
1       0       1
1       1       0
```

Only 2 dtypes in my original table.

```
case_history            object     # text column
cleaned_text            object     # text column
401k deduction           int64     # 0-10
assistance manual        int64     # 0-10
assistance quick         int64     # 0-10
```

Comment: can you print the contents of dtype?

Comment: @Yuca There are only two dtypes in the original dataset.

Comment: for a solution along the lines of your initial efforts, look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3501382/checking-whether-a-variable-is-an-integer-or-not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do `select_dtypes` + `clip` then `update`

```
df.update(df.select_dtypes(include=np.number).clip(upper=1))
Out[118]: 
   col1  col2  col3
0     1     1     0
1     1     0     1
2     1     1     0
```