# Name not defined error while using eval((input)) for an if statement

Tags: python-3.x, input, eval

I'm studying Zed shaw's learn python 3 the hard way book and there's a part in the code i'm trying to improve.

My aim was to have an if statement with the condition that the input the user gives is of int type.

```
def gold_room():
    print("This room is full of gold. How much do you take?")

    choice = eval(input("> "))
    if type(choice) is int:
        how_much = choice
    else:
        print("Man, learn to type a number.")

    if how_much < 50:
        print("Nice, you're not greedy, you win!")
        exit(0)
    else:
        print("You greedy bastard!")

gold_room()
```

It works if the input is indeed an integer but if I type in a string i get the error:
`NameError: name 'string' is not defined`

I tried to use int() but then if the input is a string I get an error.
Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Is `eval(input("> "))` really from the book? You should not use `eval` esp. on user inputs, because it is [dangerous](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html).

Comment: The `eval` function is for running code from text ("it evaluates the text as code").
What you said you want is to check that what the user typed is an integer. So I think that `eval` is not the way to go.

Comment: No I learned about eval() form the internet while reading up on input(). That article you gave went mostly over my head. So if I shouldn't use eval() is their an another way to check whether the input is an int in an if statement?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Checking whether a variable is an integer or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3501382/checking-whether-a-variable-is-an-integer-or-not)

Comment: @Lenormju not really, the methods there do work with the if statement, but I still get the same error if the input is a string. And even for that to work I still have to use eval() because input() converts to strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `choice = int(input("> "))`. The [`int` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int) will convert the string that the `input` function gives you into an integer. But if it can't, it will raise an exception ([ValueError](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#ValueError)), that you may want to try-except.

Comment: That seems to be the best way to go about it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Using @Lenormju 's answer I wrote this and it worked like a charm.

```
def gold_room():
    print("This room is full of gold. How much do you take?")
    #  used try to check whether the code below raises any errors
    try:
        choice = int(input("> "))
        how_much = choice
    # except has code which would be executed if there is an error
    except:
        dead("Man, learn to type a number.")
    # else has code which would be executed if no errors are raised
    else:
        if how_much < 50:
            print("Nice, you're not greedy, you win!")
            exit(0)
        else:
            dead("You greedy bastard!")
```

Thank you to everyone who took the time out to respond