# brand new to python - silly/obvious question

Tags: python

I am brand new to coding and trying to learn Python.  I cannot work out how to code an elif statement such that if the variable is an integer there is a certain output, but if it is not an integer then something else is printed.  I keep getting an error.  I am trying to write a program that can analyse the variable "x" and if x is a number it will print saying it is below 2 or 2 or more, but if x is anything else including a string, it will print "something else"

```
x = 2
if x < 2:
    print("Below 2")
elif x >= 2:
    print("Two or more")
else:
    print("Something else")

x = world

if x < 2:
    print("Below 2")
elif x >= 2:
    print("Two or more")
else:
    print("Something else")
```

Comment: try [`isinstance`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance)

Comment: Your problem. world must be in quotes, as it is a string.

Comment: "_I keep getting an error_" You should tell us what the error is.

Comment: This code should throw loads of syntax errors that will point you in the right direction.  Additionally, have a look at the `isinstance` function for determining types.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Checking whether a variable is an integer or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3501382/checking-whether-a-variable-is-an-integer-or-not)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. I suggested an existing thread that should answer your question. If it doesn't help, you'll need to [edit] your question, make the title more descriptive, and provide a [mre] including the full error message.

Comment: @S3DEV Syntax errors? No, there's only `NameError: name 'world' is not defined`

Comment: @wjandrea - Comparing a string to int using '>' should throw an error as well.  (Does on my system)

Comment: @S3DEV True, though it doesn't get to that point with OP's code. And that's a `TypeError`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a couple of different ways you might use to determine if x is an int:

```
x = "a"
# also try with x = 5

# option 1
if type(x) == int:
    print("int")
else:
    print("not int")

# option 2
if isinstance(x, int):
    print("int")
else:
    print("not int")
```

Comment: that is very helpful, thank you very much.  I think I have now solved it based on your answer.  See below, this works.  is this most efficient way?

`x = "word"
if type(x) == int:
    if x < 2:
        print("Below 2")
    elif x >= 2:
        print("Two or more")
else:
    print ("something else")`

Comment: It's bad practice to use `type()` cause it'll ignore subclasses. Prefer `isinstance()`.

Comment: @wjandrea - please could you write out how I would change my code to remove `type` and use `isinstance`?

Comment: You're probably OK with type if you're just dealing with "integers" vs "non-integers" - it seems rather unlikely that you will be subclassing int in your code! However, you would just change if type(x) == int: to if isinstance(x, int): - a straight line for line swap.