# How do I accept 'any integer' as a condition in Python?

Tags: python

I have a program which contains a list, and in this list are either strings or objects of a class `A`. A sample list looks something like this:

```
['foo', 'bar', A('m',2), 'asdf', A('c', 2)]
```

As you can see, the class accepts a character and an integer value for its constructor.

I'm trying to write a conditional such that it finds the number of occurrences of the function with a specific first parameter. For instance, I want to find how many items in the list are of the form `A('m', x)` where `x` is any integer, which in this case would be 1.

How could I write an if statement to check for these elements? For now, I have:

```
if (listEle = A(desiredCharacter, any(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)))
```

Is this correct, and if yes, is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by doing this?

Comment: You can check it it's an integer by using `is int`.

Comment: See:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3501382/checking-whether-a-variable-is-an-integer-or-not

Comment: @12944 No. Maybe you mean `isinstance`?

Comment: @12944qwerty Pretty sure you meant `type(something) is int`, not `something is int`.

Comment: @iBug @mkrieger1 I've used `is int` multiple times and it always returns correctly. However, `isinstance` and `type` both are good solutions as well...

Comment: If you consider correct that `1 is int` is `False` then yes.

Answer (score 0):

Strange question, but

```
class A(object):
  def __init__(self, char, var):
  self.char = char

# Test an instance
a = A('m',8)
type(a) == A #True

# Number of occurrences of instances of A in a list
mylist = [0,1,a,2,A('f',3)]
len(list(filter(lambda el: type(el)==A, mylist))) #or the following
sum(list(map(lambda el: isinstance(el,A), mylist)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do also:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, name, num):
        self.name = name
        self.num = num

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'My name: {self.name}\nMy num: {self.num}'


a1 = A('m', 2)
a2 = A('e', 7)
l = ['foo', 'bar', a1, 'asdf', a2]

for item in l:
    if isinstance(item, A) and isinstance(item.num, int):
        print(item)
```