# How can I write a function that returns all negative numbers as well as checks if the input are only integers and floating point numbers?

Tags: python, for-loop

Write a function find_negatives that takes a list l of numbers as an argument and returns a list of all negative numbers in l. If there are no negative numbers in l, it returns an empty list.

```
def find_negatives(l):
    l_tmp = []
    for num in l:
        if num < 0:
            l_tmp.append(num)
    return l_tmp

#Examples
find_negatives([8, -3.5, 0, 2, -2.7, -1.9, 0.0])     # Expected output: [-3.5, -2.7, -1.9]
find_negatives([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])                   # Expected output: []
```

**This is part I am having trouble with below:**

**Write a function find_negatives2 that works the same as find_negatives with the following two additions:**

**If l is not a list, it returns the string "Invalid parameter type!"
If any of the elements in l is neither an integer nor a floating pointer number, it returns the string "Invalid parameter value!"**

**What I have so far**

```
def find_negatives2(l):
    l_tmp1 = []
    if type(l) != list:
        return "Invalid parameter type!"
    else:
       for num in l:

Examples:
find_negatives2([8, -3.5, 0, 2, -2.7, -1.9, 0.0])      # Expected output: [-3.5, -2.7, -1.9]
find_negatives2([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])                    # Expected output: []
find_negatives2(-8)                                    # Expected output: 'Invalid parameter type!'
find_negatives2({8, -3.5, 0, 2, -2.7, -1.9, 0.0})      # Expected output: 'Invalid parameter type!'
find_negatives2([8, -3.5, 0, 2, "-2.7", -1.9, 0.0])    # Expected output: 'Invalid parameter value!'
find_negatives2([8, -3.5, 0, 2, [-2.7], -1.9, 0.0])    # Expected output: 'Invalid parameter value!'
```

I am not sure how to proceed. I am not sure how to check each type within the list

Comment: What's the problem? Is there an error or do you not know how to proceed?

Comment: I do not know how to proceed. I am not sure how to check each type in the list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try code below:

```py
def find_negatives2(l):
    l_tmp1 = []
    if not isinstance(l, list):
        return "Invalid parameter type!"
    else:
       for num in l:
         if not (isinstance(num, float) or isinstance(num, int)):
           return "Invalid parameter value!"
         else:
           if num < 0:
             l_tmp1.append(num)
    return l_tmp1
assert find_negatives2([8, -3.5, 0, 2, -2.7, -1.9, 0.0])      == [-3.5, -2.7, -1.9]
assert find_negatives2([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])                    == []
assert find_negatives2(-8)                                    == 'Invalid parameter type!'
assert find_negatives2({8, -3.5, 0, 2, -2.7, -1.9, 0.0})      == 'Invalid parameter type!'
assert find_negatives2([8, -3.5, 0, 2, "-2.7", -1.9, 0.0])    == 'Invalid parameter value!'
assert find_negatives2([8, -3.5, 0, 2, [-2.7], -1.9, 0.0])    == 'Invalid parameter value!'
```

All assertions will be validated.

##### Explanation

`isinstance` checks whether its first argument is an instance of its second argument or not. Using this function, you can check any variable type. Please note that using `type(l) != list` is not a good approach to check variable's type. If you are interested to know why, this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3501382/checking-whether-a-variable-is-an-integer-or-not) might help you.

Comment: This works, but I do have a question. What does the check = false do?

Comment: @PythonNewb Sorry, I used it in the previous version of my answer and forgot to delete it. I have edited the answer as per your comment.

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track; you just need to make a loop for type comparisons:

```
# (...)
else:
    for num in l:
        if type(num) not in (int, float):
            return "Invalid parameter type!"
        # (...)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve what you are looking for with:

```
def find_negatives(l):
    if type(l) != list or any(str(x).isnumeric() for x in l) == False:
        return 'Invalid parameter type!'
    l_tmp = []
    for num in l:
        if num < 0:
            l_tmp.append(num)
    return l_tmp
```

All you have to do is check whether the input is a list and if any element of the input is not a number.

Comment: hmmm... converting a value to text, to then check if it would make a valid number, doesn't sound like a great deal to me. Furthermore, as per the problem statement, the string "-1" should not be a valid number, because it is a string.

Comment: `any(str(x).isnumeric() for x in l)` is equal to `False` if **none** of the strings you check is numeric. You should be checking `if not all` of them are numeric (if you want to do it this way).