# Python: If/elif statement chooses the wrong option

Tags: python

```
def palindrome_checker(a):
    if type(a) == "str":
        list1 = list(a.split(" "))
    elif type(a) == "int":
        stringified_a = str(a)
        list1 = list(stringified_a)
    else:
        list1 = a     
    list2 = list1[::-1]
    if list1 == list2:
            print("It's a palindrome")
    else:
            print("It's not a palindrome")
```

This is an unnecessarily complicated palindrome checking script that covers different user inputs.
However, if presented with an int 1234 - it omits the "elif type = int" and "jumps" to else statement, assigns list1 with an int, and the program returns an error, since it's applying indexing to an int.

I tried debugging via "prints" at different stages, and i see that my script detects 1234 as an 'int' but still decides to jump to else, without stringifying the integer.

I'm new to python, and i feel like i'm missing something very obvious here and i'm low key embarrassed but i can't see whats wrong at all...

Comment: you are comparing type against str (the type name), that's never true, i;e; `int` is never `'int'`

Comment: Verify your assumptions: start your interpreter, enter `type("") == "str"` and `type(1) == "int"`, observe that the result is `False` in both cases. Then enter `type("")` and `type(1)` and see that they are not strings.

Comment: Also note that `list("a ba".split(" "))` is `["a", "ba"]`, not `["a", "b", "a"]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `isinstance(a, str)` instead of `type(a) == "str"` and likewise to check for integer.

Answer (score 0):

That's because `type()` is not what you need! As documented in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3501382/checking-whether-a-variable-is-an-integer-or-not), it is not a valid and flexible option!

So, try using `isinstance(a, int)`, like so:

```
def palindrome_checker(a):
    if isinstance(a, str):
        list1 = list(a.split(" "))
    elif isinstance(a, int):
        stringified_a = str(a)
        list1 = list(stringified_a)
    else:
        list1 = a
    list2 = list1[::-1]
    if list1 == list2:
        print("It's a palindrome")
    else:
        print("It's not a palindrome")


palindrome_checker(1234)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
def palindrome_checker(a):
a = str(a)

list1 = list(a)
list2 = list1[::-1]

if list1 == list2:
        print("It's a palindrome")
else:
        print("It's not a palindrome")
```

Comment: The question was about checking the type for if/else conditions.