# Why does "k != int" always return True?

Tags: python

The first judgment statement "k != int" always evaluates to True, but I do not know why.

This is my function:

```
def falling(n, k):
    if k != int or k > n:
        return "error"
    elif k <= 0:
        return 1
    elif k > 0:
        return n * falling(n-1, k-1)


print(falling(5, 3))
```

I found [some suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3501382/checking-whether-a-variable-is-an-integer-or-not) that I should use

```
isinstance(<var>, int)
```

But I just do not know why

```
if k != int:
```

did not work.

Comment: *print(type(int))* for a clue. Also why do you test *k* but not *n*. Not all return paths are valid for the expression *n \* falling(n-1, k-1)*

Comment: @CtrlZ thanks for your advices, 'n' should be tested ,too. Because this is just a normal 
positive integers factorial function .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python Interpreter, if you calculate `int`, it will show

```
>>> int
<class 'int'>
```

That is, the `int` is a class named `int`.

In `k != int`, you are comparing the variable `k` to the class `int`.
You know, `k` is an integer. It is not a class.
Therefore, `k != int` is always true. An integer is not equal to a class.
You are not checking whether `k` has the `int` type. You are checking whether `k` is the class `int`.

Check this interpreter output.

```
>>> a = int
>>> a == int
True
```

Here, the variable `a` is indeed the class `int`. It is not an integer. Hence, `a == int` is `True`.